Hashing an R function
I am interested in hashing a function to see if it has changed. In my experimenting it seems that hashing a function does not only depend on the exact source of it. Why is this? And how can I hash a function so that it remains the same even if the exact same function is redefined?
In this example the two hashes are different. Is there anyway to hash these functions to be the same?
f <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}

rlang::hash(f)

f <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}

rlang::hash(f)


Edit: to see that the above produces different hashes paste above code in one script and source it. Alternatively define f, check its hash, run f with any value and check hash again and observe that it has changed.
See output:
> f <- function(x) {
+   x + 1
+ }

> rlang::hash(f)
[1] "47a6d286b1703564a0e61d59dec44ddf"

> f <- function(x) {
+   x + 1
+ }

> rlang::hash(f)
[1] "1a394338c31105654b138a2d8d92748c"


If I copy and paste your code, I get exactly the same hash for both.

Can you please [edit] your question so that it includes the steps necessary to reproduce your problem, as well as showing the output? Thanks

If I define, print and hash each function in turn, they are still both the same. If I define one, print it, then hash it, then define a second time and hash without printing, only then do I get a different result.

print(f, useSource = FALSE) should keep the hash intact.

Depending on what you need to check identity for, it might be better to compare/hash body(f) and formals(f) — those should always stay the same.

The hash can also change after the function has been executed twice - this is due to it being JIT compiled for second use.

It appears that body also changes when f is redefined. formals does not change but when changing the function itself to f <- function(x) {   x + 2 } formals will be the same as the previous version of f

An alternative would be to define your own function my_hash <- function(f) rlang::hash(capture.output(f)) which should always give the same result. That's because rlang::hash ultimately hashes a binary serialized object, such as R might write with serialize(). The details of that serialization can change according to the way the object is represented internally in R, which might be subject to change depending on how the object is stored or has been used (the exact details of serialization aren't fully explained in R internals).

@alethor Ah yes, unfortunately the body expression also carries the srcref. You can work around this by setting its attributes() to NULL (you can’t do this with the function itself, since it will modify the function).

@AllanCameron thanks, I'll probably end up using something like that!

@alethor the only caveat is that if for some reason the function is purposefully byte-compiled between tests, the hash would change. For completeness you could have my_hash <- function(f) rlang::hash(grep("<bytecode", capture.output(f), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE))

@AllanCameron - could be safer to use deparse(f) which won't capture the bytecode (or environment) tag.

Thanks for the info @AllanCameron, I'll use deparse then like Iroha suggested

capture.output() also has the issue that it uses the source reference, so two identical functions will have different outputs if they have e.g. different whitespace.

Good points; deparse is better here than capture.output
